# Why is this array filled this way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following code from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag). The only difference is that I'm using a multiple select:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { options } = event.target;
    const keys = Object.keys(options)
    let values = keys.map(k => {
      if (options[k].selected) {
        return options[k].value
      }
    });

    console.log(values);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite La Croix flavor:
        </label>
        <select multiple onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
          <option value="lime">Lime</option>
          <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
          <option value="mango">Mango</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click e.g. "lime", the console output is:

```
[null, "lime", Object, Object]
```

Why is the `values` array filled this way, and not just `["lime"]`?

Example code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tppyox?file=index.js).

## update

This seems to be some kind of issue with StackBlitz, since it works as expected with JSFiddle and CodeSandbox. I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/448). Thanks for the answers!

Comment: because your using  `keys.map(`,

Comment: FYI, you could use the [`.selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) property to get the list you want. IE would need a polyfill though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be left with Object (I'm not), what I get is undefined. That's because you're mapping over all the elements and for the non selected ones you're not returning anything (so you're returning undefined).

You can filter out those undefined items:

```
const values = keys
  .filter(k => options[k].selected)
  .map(k => options[k].value);
```

Or you could do it in one operation with reduce:

```
const values = keys.reduce((arr, k) =>
  options[k].selected ? [...arr, options[k].value] : arr, []
);
```

Or you could use a traditional loop and push on to an array if the condition is met.

Comment: I think it would be a little more sensible to first `.filter()`, then `.map()`... `keys.filter(k => options[k].selected).map(k => options[k].value)`

Comment: Strange, I don't get `undefined`, as [here](https://imgur.com/a/yFCRxVw).

Comment: Strange, what browser/version are you using and what's the value of the Object? I'm getting undefined in your example on stackblitz

Comment: @DominicTobias Very strange! I'm using Google Chrome Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: @DominicTobias the same code in CodeSandbox.io gives the `undefined`, so I suspect something is up with StackBlitz.

Comment: Very strange! Since we don't see it on there I wonder if it's some settings or something that's messed up in your localstorage etc. Try visiting the url on a private browser instance

Comment: One extra improvement: use object.values intead of object.keys.... That way the functions become simpler like .filter(option => option.selected)

Comment: @DominicTobias same thing on incognito! Strange. I've opened an issue on their GitHub rep. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code on jsfiddle and I was only getting undefined values inside the log because the map function is returning undefined if not selected.

```
let values = keys.map(k => {
  if (options[k].selected) {
    return options[k].value
  }
});
```

returns `[undefined, "lime", undefined, undefined]`

Comment: Strange, I don't get `undefined`, as [here](https://imgur.com/a/yFCRxVw).

Comment: I guess so, shouldn't return object at all ^^

Answer (score 0):

Small modification on your code, return blank value if it is not selected and then apply filter at the end

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { options } = event.target;
    const keys = Object.keys(options)
    let v=''; 
    let values = keys.map(k => {
      if (options[k].selected) {
         v=options[k].value
      }
      else{
        v='';
      }
      return v
    })

    console.log(values.filter(x => x != ''));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `map` callback you are not always returning a value, thus `undefined` values are produced.

You could chain `Array.from`, `filter` and `map`:

```
let values = Array.from(event.target.options)
                  .filter(opt => opt.selected)
                  .map(opt => opt.value);
```